# How to get all submitted MultipartFiles, regardless of their name

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, servlets

I would like a user to be able to submit any number of files with arbitrary name and origfilename.

How would one get a list of submitted files in a request?

```
@RequestParam(name = "*") MultipartFile[] files
```

I was hoping using regex or similar in name parameter would work, but all my testing failed.

Equivalent in Flask would be

```
request.files
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Related question: [Getting files in controller without @RequestParam name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59388757/getting-files-in-controller-without-requestparam-name?rq=1)

You can get requested multipart files by using `MultipartRequest#getFileMap` like this:

```
MultipartRequest multipartRequest = .....
Map<String, MultipartFile> fileMap = multipartRequest.getFileMap();
MultipartFile[] files = fileMap.values().toArray(new MultipartFile[0]);
...
```

Also you can get all the files by using `MultipartRequest#getMultiFileMap` even when the same parameter name is assigned to multiple files for example:

```
    <input type="file" name="file1"/>file1
    <input type="file" name="file2"/>file2
    <input type="file" name="file2"/>file2X
```

Spring's `DispatcherServlet`/`MultipartFilter` wraps `HttpServletRequest` object in `MultipartHttpServletRequest`(extending `MultipartRequest`) object when you send a `multipart/form-data` with a request and `MultipartRequest` can be a controller's method argument.

So your controller's method will be something like this:

```
    @RequestMapping("upload")
    public String upload(MultipartRequest multipartRequest) {

        Map<String, MultipartFile> fileMap = multipartRequest.getFileMap();
        MultipartFile[] files = fileMap.values().toArray(new MultipartFile[0]);

        // Use when the same parameter name is assigned to multiple files.
        // MultiValueMap<String, MultipartFile> multiFileMap = multipartRequest.getMultiFileMap();
        // MultipartFile[] files = multiFileMap.values().stream().flatMap(values -> values.stream()).toArray(MultipartFile[]::new);

        for (MultipartFile multipartFile : files) {
            System.out.println("param name: " + multipartFile.getName());
            System.out.println("filename: " + multipartFile.getOriginalFilename());
            System.out.println("size: " + multipartFile.getSize());

        }

        return ".....";
    }
```

When you send '1.jpg'(parameter name is 'file1') and '2.jpg'(parameter name is 'file2'), you get the output like this:

```
param name: file1
filename: 1.jpg
size: 155152
param name: file2
filename: 2.jpg
size: 154015
```

**[UPDATE]**

I have found a more simple solution. `Map<String, MultipartFile>`/`MultiValueMap<String, MultipartFile>`can also be a controller's method argument with `@RequestParam` annotation whose name attribute is empty.
Therefore you can simplify the controller's method like this:

```
@RequestMapping("upload")
public String upload(@RequestParam Map<String, MultipartFile> fileMap) {
    MultipartFile[] files = fileMap.values().toArray(new MultipartFile[0]);
    .......
    return ......
}
```

or

```
@RequestMapping("upload")
public String upload(@RequestParam MultiValueMap<String, MultipartFile> multiFileMap) {

    MultipartFile[] files = multiFileMap.values().stream().flatMap(values -> values.stream())
            .toArray(MultipartFile[]::new);
     .......
     return ......
}
```

**See Also**

[Javadoc of DispatcherServlet#checkMultipart](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.html#checkMultipart-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest-)
[Javadoc of MultipartFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/support/MultipartFilter.html)
[Javadoc of MultipartResolver#resolveMultipart](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartResolver.html#resolveMultipart-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest-)
[Javadoc of MultipartHttpServletRequest](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartHttpServletRequest.html)
[Javadoc of RequestParamMapMethodArgumentResolver](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/annotation/RequestParamMapMethodArgumentResolver.html)[UPDATE]